# VisualStudioのインジケータについて

Tags: c#, visual-studio

VisualStudio Enterprise 2015 のコード情報インジケータ (メソッドやプロパティなどの上に表示される参照数) は、メンバー変数 (フィールド) に表示させることは出来ませんか？
一時的にプロパティにすることで再現できるのですが、この手間がなかなか面倒です。
全ての変数にインジケータを表示させるのは無理だとしても、せめてpublicなメンバには表示させたいです。
良い方法をお持ちの方が居ましたらご享受下さい。
また、出来るけれどスべきではないといった反対意見がありましたら報告下さい。

Comment: 今のところCodeLensは関数メンバーにしか対応していないので、フィールドからプロパティに変更するしかありません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgrhoさんがコメントされているように、CodeLensはフィールドに対応しておらず、尚且つ設定変更や拡張を行うこともできません。
オブジェクト指向のカプセル化のためにもC#言語においてフィールドをクラス外からアクセスすべきではありません。ですので

> せめてpublicなメンバには表示させたいです。

という要望の時点でクラス設計が適切でないことが予想されます。

なお、Visual Studioであれば「すべての参照を検索」機能により指定したメンバーの参照個所をリスト表示することができます。この機能で代替にならないでしょうか？